# Compute the intraday pivot points

Tags: equities, technical-analysis

I am interested in calculating and identifying the pivot points on a candlestick plot (i.e. stock values) for different time intervals (e.g. 1min, 5mins, 15mins, 1hour, ...). What is the best way to compute them? Do I need to use second derivative to find them? Do I have to implement a machine learning model to identify them. I am a bit confused  how to do that.

**EDIT**

Be aware that I am not just interested by the pivot pivot point as you can see in this picture https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/0*tmD0hyyTxbrP1Se1. I am also interested by the intraday pivot points. I mean all the major pivot points within a trading day

[image]

If I use the @patrick's answer, I only have the red circles on the above picture, but I want to add the green circles as well.

**EDIT**
[image]
After computing the intraday pivot points, I guess it will look like this on an candlestick plot.

The thing is stock prices is a stochastic process. Most often it is not differentiable. At the beginning, I wanted to smooth the curve and use second derivative to find pivot points. Not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Pivot points can be calculated using standard linear algebra. Do you have a specific pivot point in mind? There are lots of them actually - Camarilla, DeMark and Fibonacci. You can use Google to find the formulas.

Example with formula: https://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/pivotpoint.asp

Comment: Yeah, but I am not just interested by the pivot points as you can see here (https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/0*tmD0hyyTxbrP1Se1). I am also interested by the intraday pivot points